# Adding role discordjs 14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hello I have a little problem with discordjs, I would like my bot to automatically add a role to a member just with guild and member id

But it keeps giving me the error members.find is not a function all the time

Here is the code:

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("Server id");   

const member = guild.members.find((m) => m.id === "User id");

member.roles.cache.add(role id)
```

Should I do it another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add roles to a member you shouldn't use `.cache` because that is only used for fetching the roles that are stored in cache. Instead try doing it like this:

```js
member.roles.add("role");
```

That should work.

- https://old.discordjs.dev//#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add

Answer (score 0):

link has moved to a new address
https://old.discordjs.dev//#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add

Comment: I suggest that you edit the post instead of posting a new one.